# Pulumi GCP and GraphQL getting error: NotSupportedTSVersion.d.ts is not a module

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, graphql, pulumi

I'm trying to build a graphql service running on Google Cloud Platform

I'm using:     "apollo-server-cloud-functions": "^3.11.1",

When I run:
pulumi up

I get:

NotSupportedTSVersion.d.ts is not a module

This is a file in node_modules/graphql

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myawesomeapp",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --no-notify --respawn --transpile-only src/server",
    "start": "node dist/server",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "build": "npm -s run clean && npm -s run generate && tsc && npm run build:schema",
    "build:schema": "ts-node src/schema/index.ts",
    "generate": "npm -s run generate:prisma",
    "generate:prisma": "prisma generate",
    "deploy": "pulumi up --yes -v 14",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "all"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@pothos/core": "^3.23.1",
    "@pothos/plugin-prisma": "^3.37.0",
    "@prisma/client": "4.8.0",
    "@pulumi/gcp": "^6.39.0",
    "@pulumi/pulumi": "^3.50.2",
    "apollo-server-cloud-functions": "^3.11.1",
    "graphql": "16.6.0",
    "graphql-scalars": "1.20.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/graphql": "^14.5.0",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "prettier": "^2.8.1",
    "prisma": "4.8.0",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "2.0.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.4"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node --transpile-only prisma/seed.ts"
  }
}
```

Here is my tsconfig.ts:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

What I want to happen is that the endpoint is deployed and that I can send graphql queries to it.

Comment: Of course when I do: npm run build, I get no errors.

Comment: Contents of node_modules/graphql/NotSupportedTSVersion.d.ts:

"Package 'graphql' support only TS versions that are >=4.1.0".

Comment: Found this: https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/languages/javascript/ and: https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/3606

Answer (score -1):

Solution seems to be not using typescript in pulumi but compiling before the pulumi deploy

Moved index.ts to src subfolder

Added to package.json:

"main": "dist/index.js"

run:
npm run build
npm run deploy